# Wearing ihram from Masjid Ayesha

Tags: umrah

Assalamu alaikum,

I am working in Haram i need to perform my first Umrah, Every one saying I can visit to masjidh al ayesha and wear Ihram and reenter to Haram is that Meeqat acceptable please clarify?

Answer (score 4):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masjid_e_Taneem):

> Masjid e Taneem is a mosque in the Al-Hil area about 5 miles away from
>   the Holy Kaaba, in Taneem, which is near Mecca and acts as Miqat (a
>   station for putting on pilgrims' garments) for people living in
>   Mecca.This mosque is also known as Masjid -e- Ayesha since Prophet
>   Mohammed 's wife Ayesha had put her Ihram (restriction on Pilgrimage)
>   from this place once. If someone is living in Mecca and wants to
>   perform Umra (pilgrimage to Mecca) then he should go to this place,
>   enter into the state of Ihram (in part by putting on pilgrim's
>   garments) and then return to Mecca so that the condition of traveling
>   for the pilgrims is also fulfilled.

Here is the hadith, from which the the mosque was given its name (and also why its the point where ihram should be worn (point of meqat) for residents of Makkah):

> Jaabir (may Allah be pleased with him) reports that because Aisha (may
>   Allah be pleased with her) was experiencing menstrual cycle the
>   Prophet (peace and blessings of Allah be on him) intstructed her to
>   perform all the various rites of Hajj except for the Tawaaf. She then
>   performed the Tawaaf after her cycle had ended. She then said, “O
>   Rasulullah (peace and blessings of Allah be on him)! While you have
>   performed Hajj and Umrah, I have performed only Hajj.” The Prophet
>   (peace and blessings of Allah be on him) then instructed her brother
>   Abdur-Rahman (may Allah be pleased with him) to take her to Tan’eem
>   and it was from there that she performed her Umrah after her Hajj
>   during the month of Dhul Hijjah.

It is also mentioned in the various umrah guides available from vendors at these places.  I would also recommend reading [this article](http://www.saudigazette.com.sa/index.cfm?method=home.regcon&contentid=2010110586794) which details common mistakes/misconceptions about hajj and umrah.

May Allah accept your prayers.