# Repeating of umra from makkah

Tags: halal-haram, fiqh, umrah

As salam alaikum warehmathulla barakathuhu 
We are hear in makkah for umra before arriving makkah we wear ihram in india

And now we want to do second umra is it allowed if we wear ihram inside the haram boundary( room) and do niyath in masjide Ayisha raw

Thanks you 
M.d yusuf

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wearing Ihram from Masjid e 'Aisha while comming from madina to perform Umrah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/23702/wearing-ihram-from-masjid-e-aisha-while-comming-from-madina-to-perform-umrah) see also https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/12070/wearing-ihram-from-masjid-ayesha?